# Handling multiple user input in RASA

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I am making a symptom checker chatbot . And I cannot figure out way to take multiple user input before analyzing it and giving output. Like, taking all the user input then giving the output after analyzing all the inputs given. Forms can be used but i am confused on how to implement on the system.

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for multiple user messages by using [`action_listen`](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/default-actions#action_listen). However, it might be hard to know when to stop listening. Depending on how many messages you're expecting from the user, it may be easiest to have a custom action loop, with the bot saying something like
"Anything else you want to add?", and accumulating the user's responses so they can all be analysed together.

Comment: You can also inform the user to type all the symptoms in a single response with comma separated. which you can parse the input in your custom actions.